# Name for servlets and filters

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

Is there a common name that i can use for servlets and filters? I want to configure them in a separate xml file but i don't want to name it 'servlets-and-filters.xml'. Is 'fragment' or 'fragments' an appropriate name?

Comment: Why use XML in the first place? Why not use annotations?

Comment: I'm in a legacy context, but i'm not configuring them themselves, as i would do it in a deployment descriptor (e.g. web.xml) i'm configuring some other properties which kind of belong to them. The technical part is no problem :) It would be nice to find a relevant, common name for both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: the simplest most appropriate name seems to be 'fragment'. Based on resources such as [Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment) and [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cweb_webfragments.html), you can safely say a fragment (e.g. web-fragment.xml) is similar to a classic deployment descriptor (web.xml) especially from the 1-to-many relation between one fragment and servlets / filters. In other words a fragment can contain many servlets and filters.